# Is this typedef required?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Is there a way to accomplish what this block of code does in C++ without using a typedef?

```
typedef int* pointer;
int a = 3;
int* ap = &a;
const pointer& apr = ap;
*apr = 4;
```

This won't do it:

```
int b = 3;
int* bp = &b; 
const int*& bpr = bp; 
*bpr = 4;
```

In fact, that second block won't compile, because the `const` makes bpr a reference to a read-only pointer, not a const reference to a read-write pointer. I was kinda hoping that parenthesis would save me:

```
const (int*)& bpr = bp;
```

...but no luck there. So do I *have* to typedef the pointer type in order create a const reference to a read-write pointer?

Comment: You never *need* a typedef.

Comment: @EdS., I invite you to answer [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308716/how-to-write-a-c-conversion-operator-returning-reference-to-array). Please do.

Comment: @chris: Nice!  Revised: *"You very rarely need a typedef"*.  10 years and I've just never found myself in that kind of situation.

Comment: @EdS., I have really vague memories of a SO post/comment about them being necessary for something, but there was no way I was going to remember where that was. All this time of that lingering in my memory and maybe this is what their example was. I mean I recently came across a typedef being necessary in order to make the name of the type an identifier, but that's just library design. Also, in terms of C, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829522/is-typedef-ever-required-in-c) could be worth looking through.

Comment: @chris a typedef is necessary if you want to declare a conversion operator to function pointer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html):

```
int* const &bpr = bp;
```

This is read as *bpr is a reference to a constant pointer to an int*.

For a sample, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f84cfa71d18b65b).

Thank you to dasblinkenlight for pointing out that the parentheses in the original answer were not required.

Comment: I think parentheses are optional there ([link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Good point, thank you. I'm too used to putting them there with references to arrays.

Comment: thanks for the note about the spiral rule. is what you have there the same as making a const reference to a pointer to an int?

Comment: @Robz, There are no const references ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d246066ba246778d)), only references to const, so it's probably the same as what you imagine it as.

Comment: ah, I see I've been thinking about this all wrong. now your answer makes sense. thanks!